# Cross platform Robot Framework library for testing GUI application

Tags: wxpython, automated-tests, robotframework

I have a cross-platform GUI application written using wxpython.  I want to test it (automatically).  Robot Framework seems an ideal way of doing that.  Does anyone know of a Robot Framework library for interacting with a GUI application (or a wxwidgets or wxpython application)?

I am aware of AutoIt, but that is Windows only.  I want Windows + Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use wx.UIActionSimulator which is a part of wxPython starting in 2.9.2. You can read about some ideas for using it (and other ideas) here:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/wxpython-users/automated$20gui$20testing/wxpython-users/8Nv_pepRx0I/dA_GgzeMKoIJ

Alternatively, there is a Sikuli project which also might work:

- http://www.sikuli.org/